# Can't find phonegap.js for Iphone

Tags: cordova

My deviceready in phonegap isnt working, so I found out that I'm still using an android javascript file from phonegap. Looking in the phonegap/lib/ios/ directory for a javascript file for IOS, I didnt find it. I downloaded phonegap again to make sure I didnt delete it previously.

I dont get this, can anybody help please?

thank you

Comment: I didnt see the phonegap.js is created automatically on startup. Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is Dreamweaver you are using with Phonegap, download the newest version from here:

http://phonegap.com/download-thankyou

Then upgrade your phonegap according to this guide:

http://idoitonamac.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-upgrade-phonegap-in-adobe.html

And be sure to open the "DefaultActivity.java" file and change "import com.phonegap.*" to "import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;"

IF it is xcode, do as commented by 'dan' and follow this guide:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-iOS-using-Xcode-4-%28Template-Version%29

(which informs you that it is indeed in the www folder of your project the javascript file is located)

Answer (score 2):

It changed the name to "cordova-1.5.0.js" (this is for the 1.5.0 version)
Also, from @Mantion answer: And be sure to open the "DefaultActivity.java" file and change "import com.phonegap.*" to "import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;"

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494778/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20%28iOS%29%20-%20Xcode%203

Hey, try this link. 
Seems pretty explicit to me and I hope it'll help.

From what I know, PhoneGap is a plugin... so you must have a /plugins folder in your app... and there it should go.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43708792/How%20to%20Install%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS

If you put it there, then it must be there...

Comment: but all it says there about the web content is "Modify the contents of the "www" directory to add your HTML, CSS and Javascript." There is nowhere mentioned where to insert the phonegap.js for IOS?

Comment: yes the app has a plugins folder, but there is nothing in it. Shouldnt there be a phonegap.js for IOS somewhere in the phonegap folder?

Comment: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-iOS-using-Xcode-4-%28Template-Version%29 . Here it's the same it says "Modify the contents of the "www" directory to add your HTML, CSS and Javascript." With a picture of phonegap.js files in the www folder. But no word on where it comes from. Please help I think I'm completely missing the problem here.

Comment: adritha84, you sent me a workarround for a phonegap plugin. I dont want to use a phonegap plugin, I just want to use phonegap. Dont want to be rude but you're answer has nothing to do with my question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I found Version 2.9.0 in Github:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/master/lib/ios/CordovaLib/cordova.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the DMG file? I believe the lib and the JS files are embedded in the DMG so you will need to run the installer.